# linux (bash) screen with backgrounded process

Tags: bash

With a clean working directory if I start the detached screen as follows

```
screen -dm bash -c "echo a>A; echo b>B;"
```

then my file A is created and contains content. (As is my file B).

With the same clean working directory if the first command is backgrounded

```
screen -dm bash -c "echo a>A&; echo b>B;" # note the & after a>A
```

then no files have content. Why is this so?

What I want to do is replace "echo a>A" with some long running process and store it's PID with the second echo. This is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Write it thus:

```
echo a>A&echo b>B
```

Or, for better readability,

```
echo a>A & echo b>B
```

When `&` is parsed your first command has already finished, so putting a `;` will result in syntax error. `echo a>A&; echo b>B` is just as

```
#Buggy program
echo a>A &
;
echo b>B
```

and will raise an error.